# Navigating to dynamically routed page in Next JS returns error

Tags: javascript, next.js

When navigating from a link in the same web app to the dynamically routed page clicking on a link the result is as intended: I navigate to the page for a product (http://localhost/1).

But when I directly navigate by naming the product number specifically in the search bar (navigating to http://localhost/2), I get the following error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined 

> | <Image src={"/../public/images/" + p.image}
                                        ^
```

So far I've tried making the types match and reading the Next JS docs on dynamically routing.

I've removed the array zero from the filter but still no resolution.

Could it be possible that the routing only works when clicking on a link in Next JS?  Is there some missing setting I've neglected?

#### pages/[pid].js

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Image from 'next/image'

import data from '../products.json'

export default function Template() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { pid } = router.query

  const p = data.filter(product => product._id == pid)[0]  // Choose one result

  return (
    <Image src={"/../public/images/" + p.image}
           height="500px"
           width="500px" />
  )
}
```

#### products.json

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Toyota",
    "image": "toyota.png"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "BMW",
    "image": "bmw.png"
  }
]
```

**Update:** I've tried to hardcode the `src` attribute in the Image tag and the new error says the other references are the issue.  So I can safely say the issue is to do with no object returned when the data object is called.

Comment: add a console.log and print your `pid` constant after getting it from `router.query`, is that `pid` worked after navigation? is it get updates?

Comment: @novonimo
When navigating from a link, the output is the product id.  `{pid: '2'}` if using `http://localhost/2`.  

When navigating straight to the page `http://localhost/2`, no console logs are produced.  Just `GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/1 500 (Internal Server Error)`.

Comment: There is also an error underneath that says `at Function.getInitialProps`.  I might not be pulling the static objects properly in Next JS.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue!

It was not enough to use Dynamic Routes by using the 'useRouter()' function.  I also had to define these two functions:

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  // No-op since getStaticPaths needs getStaticProps to be called.
  return { props: {} }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const dynamicFiles = products.map(product => (
    {
      params: { pid: String(product._id) },  // Product IDs are ints in JSON file
    }
  ))

  return {
    paths: dynamicFiles,
    fallback: false
  }
}
```

This makes sense since you wouldn't want random paths to be used as a variable.  For example, then a user would be able to specify `http://localhost/1234` when `1234` is not a valid option.

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes/implement-getstaticprops